# Dependency issues with building .NET Core build on TFS

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, tfsbuild

Been trying to get the build to work on TFS build agent. The solution compiles fine on the local machine but once I tried to queue a build on TFS I got the dependency could not be resolved issues.

Here's the log file

```
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (11, 0)
The dependency BundlerMinifier.Core >= 2.3.327 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (15, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.ApplicationInsights >= 2.2.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (15, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore >= 2.0.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (18, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery >= 1.1.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (17, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication >= 1.1.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (17, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies >= 1.1.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (18, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization >= 1.1.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (18, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors >= 1.1.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (17, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal >= 1.1.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (18, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal >= 1.1.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (17, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation >= 1.1.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (18, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection >= 1.1.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (17, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection >= 1.1.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (18, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions >= 1.1.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (17, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions >= 1.1.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (16, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics >= 1.1.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (16, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions >= 1.1.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (18, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions >= 1.1.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (15, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (21, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (15, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting >= 1.1.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (21, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting >= 1.1.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (18, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions >= 1.1.0 could not be resolved.
F:\B\848\Sources\RELEASE\MVRApplication\project.json (7, 0)
The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions >= 1.1.0 could not be resolved.
```

Here's the project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.3.327",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "2.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0"  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "precompile": [ "dotnet restore" ],
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

I made sure to add `"precompile": [ "dotnet restore" ],` in the script section but TFS still gives me the dependency error. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: precompile script doesn't work for me, you can add command line step to restore packages.

Comment: There is a related article https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding command line step/task with dotnet command to restore the packages.

Related article: [Build and deploy your ASP.NET Core app to Azure](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure)

Comment: Thanks @starain-MSFT, this helped.